# RSS Widget on theme

Tags: rss

I want to display some external RSS Feeds in my theme - not on a sidebar - just before a homepage content that I'm building.

Is there a core shortcut or method to display RSS on themes?

Answer (score 3):

You may use the method provided by Jeff here :

http://digwp.com/2009/11/import-and-display-feeds-in-wordpress/

read the comments as the feed.php include is not required.

Answer (score 1):

See the [codex for fetch_feed](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/fetch_feed), the page has also e example to learn and modify. Alternativ you can use plugins for more paramters, as example see for the plugin RSSImport.